# Stimulsoft reports issue in firefox when exporting reports

Tags: stimulsoft

I am developing a report using stimulsoft report designer 2009.3.600. I gave the report name "Account Registration" and when I save the reports to formats like .docx, .xls and .pdf it takes the report name "Account Registration" and the extension correctly. But when I do this in Firefox version 20.0.1 or most other earlier versions as I have tried, it saves as a File without any extension and only display the "Account" part in the file name. Does anyone know the reason for this to happen ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already fixed.
Use the latest release 2013.1.

Comment: I cannot upgrade since I am using this with Sitecore. However as a workaround Removing spaces in the "Report Alias" property solved the problem.